# aliased cleos, how to alias nodeos?

Tags: cleos, nodeos

I aliased my cleos on port 5555 and 7777, like in the tutorial https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/getting-the-software

I was wondering if there was a way to alias nodeos as well, because when I run it from the bash it gives me this error on port 8888.

```
Failed to connect to nodeos at http://127.0.0.1:8888/; is nodeos running?
```

Comment: You get this error when you try to execute cleos i think. Right?

Comment: If you are using cleos, you can change port by editing cleos.sh file.